# How to give a null check in both if and else statement

Tags: javascript

```
if (!away) {
   return self.data.a1;
}
else {
   return self.data.a2;
}
```

I am getting undefined in both if and else statement for self.data

Comment: Learn javascript here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: If *self.data* is undefined, then you should be getting an error in the console when trying to read either the *a1* or *a2* property. The code doesn't modify the value, so if it's null or undefined, it had that value previously.

Comment: If self is also undefined,then what will you get???

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want

```
If (!away && self && self.data) {
```

Or just wrap your in a try/catch and handle the exception locally.

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can check if they're defined

```
if (!away) {
    if(typeof self !== 'undefined' && 
       typeof self.data !== 'undefined' && 
       typeof self.data.a1 !== 'undefined')
        return self.data.a1;
} else {
    if(typeof self !== 'undefined' && 
       typeof self.data !== 'undefined' && 
       typeof self.data.a2 !== 'undefined')
        return self.data.a2;
}
```

Comment: @RobG haha you're sitting there typing that, why didn't you edit my answer :)  . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your `return` statement only works if it is contained within a function scope, such as:

```
var away = false;
var self = {
    data: {
        a1: 'hi',
        a2: 'ho'
    }
};

var a = function(){
  console.log(self, self.data);
    if (!away) {
        return self.data.a1;
    } else {
        return self.data.a2;
    }
};

console.log(a()); // returns 'hi
```

But if that was obvious to you and that's not the problem you're having, then yes, perhaps a `console.log` of `self.data` will help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check is to do it like:

```
if(typeof(self.data.a1) != "undefined"){ /* do whatever shall be done in this case */ }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but typeof is not a function, it's an operator in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could write the if condition on one line, try it in your console:

```
var self = {'data': { 'a1': 'a1' } };

console.log((!away && self.data) && (self.data.a1 || self.data.a2))

self.data.a2 = 'a2';
self.data.a1 = null;

console.log((!away && self.data) && (self.data.a1 || self.data.a2))
```

logs a1 and a2.